# How does Magento 2 process ko statements and how to use them?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, magento-2.0, knockoutjs

In Magento 2 templates I've found some `ko` statements such as

```
<form class="form form-shipping-address" id="co-shipping-form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-fields') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<div id="shipping-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn) -->
    <div class="field choice" data-bind="visible: !isFormInline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="shipping-save-in-address-book" data-bind="checked: saveInAddressBook" />
        <label class="label" for="shipping-save-in-address-book">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Save in address book'"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I understood it has something to do with knockoutjs but I'm not used of this library at all.

- how does Magento process such statements ?
- how to use those statements in a custom module ?

Comment: Below is two article help you [Magento 2 UI knockoutjs](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-ui-knockoutjs-using-container-less-ko-template-gettemplate) [How to use Knockout in Magento 2](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/knockout-js-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty wide open question, but from what I understand of Knockout, those comments aren't processed by Magento at all -- they're [Knockout syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) for creating [container-less statements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).  i.e. it's the knockout javascript library that processes them.

Probably best [to get started with the official docs](http://knockoutjs.com/) until someone writes up a tutorial on how Magento integrates with Knockout (similar to my [RequireJS article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs))